# Release created in Sourcetree do not appear in GitHub

Tags: github, atlassian-sourcetree

I used the gitflow option in sourcetree to start an new release. however when I finish the release and push the release up to github the created tags are available on github but the created release not.

why is that and how can I enable that releases from sourcetree also become visible on github?

Answer (score 0):

A release in GitFlow is represented by a branch and/or tag, but these are pure Git things.

A Release in GitHub is a tag that's annotated with additional metadata (such as the release notes and generated artifacts). But it's essentially a purely GitHub thing that references a Git Tag.

When making a release in SourceTree, only the Git elements are made. So so after pushing there isn't anything "missing" everything that was created locally has been pushed successfully to GitHub.

To create the GitHub Release, you can then either create a release from the pushed tag in the Web UI, or you can use the GitHub CLI to create a Release:

```
gh release create v1.3.4 --notes ""
```